“Error: Unknown command Codegen” Playwright -Java on IntelliJ Mac
I am doing a POC on Playwright using java and I running the below  Codegen command on Maven - Intellij but I am seeing the “unknown command : Codegen”. Can someone please let me know where did I go wrong
mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="codegen demo.playwright.dev/todomvc"


Worth a look for helping surface some searchable keywords: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
